# Map info extraction ENVI header

Tags: qgis, python, envi

Does anyone have any idea about getting the map info from an ENVI header file?

This is my file.hdr as shown in the text editor:

```
ENVI
description = {
C:\xxxx\yyyy\Desktop\filename.}
samples = 36000
lines   = 36000
bands   = 1
header offset = 0
file type = ENVI Standard
data type = 4
interleave = bsq
byte order = 0
map info = {Geographic Lat/Lon, 1, 1, 20, 28, 0.000222222222222222, 0.000222222222222222,WGS-84}
coordinate system string = {GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]}
band names = {
Band 1}
```

I would like to use the "pixel easting" (20), "pixel northing" (28) and "pixel dimension" (0.000222) in a python script. Is there any Python library about that?
It seems like a simple matter, but I still can't get through it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spectral https://www.spectralpython.net/index.html

It is a python package for processing hyperspectral image data. It can read ENVI header file. Asimple code could be:

```
import spectral.io.envi as envi

lib = envi.open("file.hdr")
map_info = lib.metadata["map info"]

# this assumes that the params you are looking for are at 3,4,5 position
pix_easting = map_info[3]
pix_northing = map_info[4]
pix_dim = map_info[5]

print(pix_easting, pix_northing, pix_dim)
```